# Error C2512 Visual C++ (And is not a circular dependency)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I know this have been asked before in stackoverflow, but the problem is no the same as in that case.

I have created a "Card" Class to hold a few data and it is used by 2 other classes.

Card.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H

#include <string>

class Card
{
public:
    Card(const char *val);
    Card();
    ~Card();
    int getValue();
    char getPalo();
    std::string getStringName();
private:
    int valueFrom(char x);
    char palo;
    int valor;
};

#endif
```

Card.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Card.h"
#include "myUtilities.h"

using namespace Uts;

Card::Card(const char *val)
{
    valor = valueFrom(val[0]);
    palo = val[1];
}

Card::Card()
{

}


Card::~Card()
{
}

int Card::getValue()
{
    return valor;
}

char Card::getPalo()
{
    return palo;
}

std::string Card::getStringName()
{
    /*...*/
}


int Card::valueFrom(char x)
{
    /*...*/
}
```

This is just the Card Class, excuse me but i have to put more code

player.h

```
    #pragma once

    #ifndef PLAYER_H
    #define PLAYER_H

    #include "card.h"

    class player
    {
    public:
        player(Card _c1, Card _c2);
        ~player();
        card c1;
        card c2;
    };

    #endif // !player_H
```

player.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "player.h"

player::player(Card _c1, Card _c2)
{//Error here

    c1 = _c1;
    c2 = _c2;
}


player::~player()
{
}
```

Then the compiler shut a C2512 error saying that card does not have a default constructor, but, ass you can see, it has.

IMPORTANT: My code is very long and stackoverflow tells me that i cannot post so much code, but CARD IS USED BY OTHER CLASS called "deck". But i think here is the problem.

Comment: `player(card _c1, card _c2);` -- What is `card`?  That is not the same thing as `Card`.  Also use either `pragma once` or `#include` guards.  There is no need to use both techniques in the same header.

Comment: Sorry is a mistake in this short version, but i check it out and of course i have "Card" and not "card"

Comment: First, get rid of / turn off the precompiled header `stdafx.h` and try again.  Second, for compiler errors, you shouldn't attempt to type in code -- then it becomes a question of whether it is a typo, or whether the code is your actual code and is the cause of the error.  Attempt to make a [mcve].

Comment: Don't retype code. Retyping can introduce typos, but also often removes problems because you write what you think the code is rather than what it actually is. Copy, paste, remove the irrelevant bits, compile, *then* post. It sounds like a lot of work but it saves time for everyone in the long run.

Answer (score -1):

Change your declaration of player(Card, Card) to player(Card const &, Card const &), and then your definition to:

```
player::player(Card const &_c1, Card const &_c2)
  : c1(_c1), c2(_c2)
{}
```